# Add zuul rate limit per user where there is no centralized authorization module

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, rate-limiting

I have a micro service architecture which is working with `Spring Zuul Gateway` like below image.
[image]

My authentication service returns `x-auth-token` which is generated by spring authentication resolver and my token repository is redis. So users should use this service to authenticate and then use other services.

All my other services connect to same redis instance, so when they receive `x-auth-token` they can get user session details. I normally do the authorization by using `@PreAuthorize` annotation and then specifying the roles that can have access to controller or method.

Everything was so far working fine. Then I have been asked to add rate-limit functionality to this architecture. So for example **a single user** should not be able to make more than 1 `POST` request to specific api in books service. Also, if there were two book service instances, I would want to both be counted as single service when its about rate limiting.

I found tons of documents that referred me to [this](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit) project called **spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit**. Looking at the document I realized it does support redis as storage (good for me because I already have redis there) and it also supports handling rate limits per users.

The problem is that my zuul gateway knows nothing about the users! It has no access to redis storage. If I give it an access to redis, the problem might be solved but another one would rise: I'm gonna need to authorize user twice which takes more time and more redis traffic! once at gateway, once at each service (to check the roles and session details).

I'm looking for solutions that are most close to this list of needs:

1. Does not change my authentication method (I cant just switch to JWT or OAuth)
2. Does not duplicate authorization or redis queries
3. Balancing the requests between my services should not effect the rate limit. If each instance of service X is requested once for single user, then user has sent two requests.
4. Hopefully there is a good spring support for the answer.
5. I would prefer to be able to change the limits dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Zuul gateway rate limiter plugin basically tracks counter of user request based
on specific key (could be user's IP, some ID, request path or custom
combinations using custom key generator) given user requests during time interval. You can add it to the
existing zuul gateway application.

Let's say the ratelimiter-gateway is using `"[clientIP][userID][method][path]"` as request counter key stored in redis, e.g. `"10.8.14.58:some@mail.com:POST:/books"`.

Here's some options I can think of:

1. If the client send some ID, you can use it directly as rate limiter
   combination key.
2. If the user only send JWT token, you can verify it's claim to get the user
   ID, assuming it's embedded in the token, using the same secret key to generate the JWT token in authn service
   as Zuul gateway app properties (using OS env credentials, vault etc.). Or
   you can just use the token as user ID.
3. Move the authorization logic to Spring zuul+ratelimiter service. It will
   validate incoming request to `author` & `books` service, get the user ID from token. And then pass it as
   another header, ex: "x-app-user-id", to the upstream services using
   SpringBoot Filter. This way, the upstream services won't do any authn logic, it's just read the user id from
   header. Communication between `author` & `books` service might be using the same header. This, of course, assuming the upstream servers won't be accessed
   directly from the outside network.

It might also be good idea to use different redis instance as the ratelimit key storage.

As for dynamic config, based on it's documentation, you can adjust the rate limit config via
properties. I don't know if it can be adjusted dynamically at runtime via
Spring Cloud Config or other remote config implementations without the gateway
app needs to be restarted.

Comment: There are some problems that I already mentioned in the question. First of all, whatever that id sent by client is, I should be able to validate them in zuul, which basically means to move authorization to zuul, which I wanted to avoid in first place. Same thing applies to other methods. Surely, something like JWT can work in this situation. But anyways, your answer was helpful, thanks.

Comment: Zuul is an ApiGateway and thus is the entry to application esp. in Microservices.So the security related checks must be done at Zuul before you let the requests get in.